# Having one row of flex containers that are going in different directions

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm trying to create a flex container with the two different areas. The left side is going to have 2 flex boxes stacked on top of each other while the right side (box one) is going to be another flex container with multiple boxes in column form. When I currently create it, it's all pushed together in the corner, looking like this.

```css
.practice-flex-container {
  display: flex;
}

.practice-flex-container div {
  border: 1px #ccc solid;
  padding: 10px
}

.practice-left-flex-container {
  flex-direction: column;
}

.practice-right-flex-container {
  flex-direction: row;
}

.left-box {
  flex: 1;
}

.box-3 {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="practice-flex-container">
  <div class="practice-left-flex-container">
    <div class="left-box">
      <h3>Search Here</h3>
      <p>_________</p>
    </div>
    <div class="left-box">
      <h3>Overall Stats: </h3>
      <p>Rewards: 127378</p>
      <p>Deposits: 127838</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="practice-right-flex-container">
    <div class="box-3">
      <h3>Box One</h3>
      <p>hello</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @PHPglue The containers aren't spanning across the whole page, but instead being pushed into the left corner

Comment: You want the "box one" got the same height, inherit from the parent flexbox-container by set in .practice-flex-container { height:100vh }, and inherith.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you need to know. `display:flex;` makes its child Elements automatically become part of its flexible layout. The children of the `display:flex;` should have `flex:auto;` to automatically take up the space available within the `display:flex;` parent. `flex-direction:row;` is the default direction for children that have a parent set to `display:flex;`. To override this you need to set `flex-direction:column;`.

Keep in mind when nesting Elements, the parents of the nested Elements need `display:flex;` for their children to become part of their flexible layout.

After doing some research, I think this is what you want:

```css
.practice-flex-container{
  box-sizing:border-box; display:flex;
}
.practice-flex-container div{
  border:1px #ccc solid; padding:10px
}
.practice-flex-container>div{
  flex:auto; flex-direction:column; display:flex;
}
.practice-flex-container>div>div{
  flex:auto;
}
.practice-flex-container>div>div>div{
  display:flex;
}
.practice-flex-container>div>div>div>div{
  flex:auto; color:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="practice-flex-container">
  <div class="practice-left-flex-container">
    <div class="left-box">
      <h3>Search Here</h3>
      <p>_________</p>
    </div>
    <div class="left-box">
      <h3>Overall Stats: </h3>
      <p>Rewards: 127378</p>
      <p>Deposits: 127838</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="practice-right-flex-container">
    <div class="box-3">
      <h3>Box One</h3>
      <p>hello</p>
      <div>more stuff here</div>
      <div>more stuff here</div>
      <div>more stuff here</div>
      <div>more stuff here</div>
      <div>more stuff here</div>
      <div>more stuff here</div>
      <div>more stuff here</div>
      <div>
        <div>stuff</div>
        <div>stuff</div>
        <div>stuff</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```